# Why cannot include specific capybara Module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Cant direct require a specific module for Capybara (`require 'capybara/helpers'`). its work for 
  `require 'capybara/dsl'`
  or
  `require 'capybara/rspec'`

result a exception:

```
(...)/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': no such file to load -- capybara/helpers.rb (LoadError)
```

I dont know why some modules alowed to load on require `capybara/?` and others not.

Comment: "capybarq" ->  you have a typo in the last letter there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

capybara/helpers is not available in the current stable version (1.1.3) of Capybara. It was [added 3 months ago](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/helpers.rb) but is only available in 2.0.0.beta4.